# In this question of elastic potential energy, why doesn’t the answer of compression come negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, potential-energy, spring

> A smooth curved track terminates in a smooth horizontal part. A spring of spring constant $400N/m$ is attached at one end of a wedge fixed rigidly with the horizontal part. A $40g$ mass is released from rest at a height of $4.9 m$ on the curved track. Find the maximum compression of the string.
>
> [image: Enter image description]

In the equation given,why isn’t spring's potential energy taken as $-\frac{1}{2} k x^2$ rather than the positive one?

Comment: Is that H. C. Verma volume 1?

Comment: Why should it be negative?

Comment: Try that numerical with a negative value of potential energy. Wouldn't you have got a complex answer? Is that admissible here?

Comment: @WrichikBasu Yes, concepts of physics vol. 1 by H. C. Verma, pg. no. 129.

Answer (score 1):

$U_e = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$ is the convention for elastic potential energy, where $x$ is the displacement of the end of the spring from its equilibrium point. It makes sense, too: it implies that you have 0 energy stored in the spring when it's at equilibrium, and that you could store more and more energy as you compress or extend it. Seems reasonable.

If it were negative, that would imply that the spring has 0 energy at equilibrium, then somehow loses energy as it extends or compresses. That seems odd.

In your problem, the energy equation is $mgh = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$. The left-hand side is the energy when the object is at rest at the top of the ramp (all of its energy is in the gravitational field). The right-hand side is the energy when the object is at rest at the bottom of the ramp (all of its energy is in the spring). Everything checks out. It just wouldn't make sense for the right-hand side to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

The elastic potential energy of a spring is $\frac{1}{2} k (\Delta x)^2$, and it's been like that from the very beginning.

Maybe you're mixing it with the force:

$F=-kx$.

But the potential energy is

$\begin{equation} E_{px}=-\int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = \int +kx dx = \frac{1}{2}k (\Delta x)^2  \end{equation}$

Comment: D'you mean "elastic" and not "gravitational"?

Comment: Of course yes haha, idk how I managed to write that. Corrected.